# How to initialize array with object in c++ by user input?

Tags: c++, xcode, computer-science

I have the code below, the credit and load successfully saves to the object but the code and title only takes the first letter of the string. I tried `course[noOfCourses_].setCode(Code)` at first, but it gives me an error:

`cannot initialize a parameter type char with lvalue char[7]`.

Another problem is that the input skips the input prompt for the title and goes directly to credit prompt.

```
void addCourse() {
    Course*course=new Course[MAX_NO_RECS];
    char Code[MAX_COURSECODE_LEN];
    char title[20];
    int credit;
    int load;

    cout << "Course Code: ";
    cin.clear();
    cin >> Code;
    cin.clear();
    course[noOfCourses_].setCode(Code[0]);
    cin.clear();
    cout << "Course Title: ";
    cin.getline(title, 20);
    cin.clear();
    course[noOfCourses_].setTitle(title[0]);
    cin.clear();
    cout << "Credits: ";
    cin >> credit;
    course[noOfCourses_].setCredits(credit);

    cout << "Study Load: ";
    cin >> load;
    course[noOfCourses_].setLoad(load);
    noOfCourses_++;

    courseList_[noOfCourses_]=course;
}
```

Comment: the error _cannot initialize a parameter type char with lvalue char[7]_ is clear, you are trying to initialize a `char x` to `char x[7]` ie: an array to a variable.
Check or post your `Cursor` class definition.

Comment: How do you implement the Course::setCode function? I think the type of its parameter should be char *.

Comment: char Course::getCode()const{
        return *courseCode_;
    } I have this and it gives me an error "EXC_BAD ACCESS"

Comment: Why is `course` a pointer to an array when you're only filling one `Course`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first way was right. You should use `course[noOfCourses_].setCode(Code)` (by the way: it would be better if the variable `Code` would not start with a capital letter).

The problem is in your `Cource::setCode` function. It seems that the parameter is a `char`. To fix it, you should change it to a `char*`

```
void Cource::setCode(char* code) {
...
}
```

Comment: Hi You're right. changing Code to code didn't give me that error anymore. but another problem I get is      char Course::getCode()const{
        return *courseCode_;
    }
        " thread EXC_BAD_Access.

Comment: try `char* Course::getCode()const{ return courseCode_; }`

Comment: Could you post the whole implementation of your course class